# JGR crashes on launching

Tags: java, r

it seems that I am the only person having this problem, so I ask some help here:

I have just installed R and JGR, loaded the library(JGR) and launched JGR(). Unfortunately, it builds the windows but it becomes unresponsive and crashes in a few seconds.
Is anybody here able to lead me to the right direction to solve the problem?

Ubuntu 16.10
JAVA version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue, and have managed to find a solution. The problem lies with the rJava package. The issue started with rJava 0.9-9, and has sadly continued with the recently release 0.9-10. But if you remove rJava and go back to version 0.9-8, JGR will start working again.